# Run python behave from python instead of command line

Tags: python, python-behave

Is there any way to run python behave from within python and not via command line?

default usage: run behave command in base folder with features/steps

desired usage: call a function (or have a certain import) which executes the behave tests in a specified folder

Comment: There appears to be example code right on the download page that imports it and runs it from a file: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/behave. In general, _yes_, if you can run it from command line, you can run it from a file

Comment: Maybe I don't see the obvious, but yes I started from the example - and they only start it with the command "behave". Could you please point me to where to they explain how to run it from a file? Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found the solution by working through the behave source code:

```
from behave.__main__ import main as behave_main
behave_main("path/to/specified/folder")
```

The main method of behave enumerates and processes all paths it finds in its arguments.

Comment: Example with additional arguments to add tag (-t) and prevent output of skipped scenarios (-k):

 `behave_main(["path/to/tutorial", '-t @run', '-k'])`

Comment: you may run a single feature file by specifying file path(absolute to relative) `behave_main("/".join([str(main.ROOT_DIR.resolve()), "features/Sample_REST_API_Testing.feature"]))` or `behave_main("~/pythonp/python-bdd/features/Sample_REST_API_Testing.feature")`

Comment: I had some errors with that approach (RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object) and found this works fine:
from behave import __main__ as behave_main
behave_main.main(folder)