# How to clean database after scenario in Python behave

Tags: python-behave

I'm pretty new to the world of `python/behave` and API testing, and I'm trying to clean the database after 1 scenario is run by calling the tag `@clean_database`.

Can you please assist?

I guess that I will need a `database_context.py` in my `context_steps` folder but I'm not sure how to do the connection to the database...

Comment: Please provide more information. Namely, what have you tried so far and what kind of database are you trying to connect to? Please narrow the scope of your question to "how can I connect to the database?" or the like, rather than "Can you please assist?" We're here to help *you* do it, not to help do it *for you*.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have 2 questions here:

> (1) How do I connect to the database?

This question doesn't involve behave, so you *should* ask this question elsewhere--perhaps on the [MySQL-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-python) thread if you're using MySQL (which you haven't specified) or on the [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) thread.

> (2) How do I use behave to call specific tags?

For the latter, check out the [documentation for running tagged tests](http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gherkin.html#controlling-your-test-run-with-tags) and see how to [run behave from your Python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829350/run-python-behave-from-python-instead-of-command-line).