# Log into the output file AND stdout in behave

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-behave

I can't see the traceback in my console during behave run when I am redirecting output to with [cmd option -o](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/behave.html#cmdoption-o)

Example log with -o:

```
2021-05-24:14:42:52, INFO     | environment.py         :22   : Before all
2021-05-24:14:42:54, INFO     | launch_test.py         :144  : 1
2021-05-24:14:42:54, INFO     | launch_test.py         :147  : feature: autogen_Generate_Cloud.feature | name: Run all projects from specified folder -- @1.1 Projects | project: Test_Beamer_Car1 | number: 1 --> FAILED
```

Example of logs without -o option enabled:

```
Exception TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
2021-05-24:14:50:57, ERROR    | launch_test.py         :141  : Exception thrown during behave run
Traceback (most recent call last):
[REDACTED TRACEBACK]
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
2021-05-24:14:50:57, INFO     | launch_test.py         :144  : 1
2021-05-24:14:50:57, INFO     | launch_test.py         :147  : feature: autogen_Generate_Cloud.feature | name: Run all projects from specified folder -- @1.1 Projects | project: Test_Beamer_Car1 | number: 1 --> FAILED
```

What I am trying to achieve? Having the latter log format but with output also redirected to file.

What I tried?:

- [Verbose flag](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/behave.html#cmdoption-v)
- [No capture stderr](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/behave.html#cmdoption-no-capture-stderr)
- Turning off formatter and output file in behave seems to do the job

I run behave from python script according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829350/run-python-behave-from-python-instead-of-command-line) SO post (with custom runner and context classes)

My current behave parameters:

```
[PATH to feature files],
"--no-summary",
"-k",
"--no-junit",
"-f=allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter",
"--no-capture",
"--no-capture-stderr",
f"-i={scenario.feature}",
f"--name={scenario.name}",
f"-o={output_file}"
```

I need to use *AllureFormatter* since the program uses allure to generate reports but it seems to catch the console output and return it only to file, not stdout or stderr as well

Comment: Ended up with parsing the output file, and printing out the traceback if the status of the test is "broken". Not particularly clean solution, but hey, it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine multiple format and outfile parameters

So normally to see output in STDOUT you would use this command

```
behave --format pretty
behave --format json
```

And if you want to send output to a file you add a output parameter

```
behave --format pretty --outfile behave.output
```

So if you just combine them, you get output to STDOUT and an output file

```
behave --format json --outfile behave.json --format pretty
```

put your STDOUT --format parameter after the outfile one just to be safe.

Comment: I have no chances to check your reply, because i no longer works for the company where I had this problem, but thanks anyway :).